# Google map is not appearing in android device

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on Google Maps v2 with Android SDK version 19. I included `google-play-services_lib` into my project.
My project was working fine but when I updated google-play-services_lib my project stopped working. There is no error in my project but it is giving exception on runtime. The updated version of google-play-service_lib is 20.

Secondly I was following  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start site here is two line code:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I do not understand what should be written in the value field ?

Comment: Did you get the certificate and API key for map?

Comment: I have got the API key but not certificate . can you please give me the link for the certificate?

Comment: It's in the link you posted, the section on getting keystore. The debug keystore and your production keystore must have different API key

Comment: Thanks lot .. map is now appearing on emulator :)